# Add a dash if empty, but not when it's focused?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to add a dash to a span if it's empty, but not if it's focused.

How do I get it to stay where it is? It's like `:not(:focus)` and `:empty:before` are fighting...

```css
.dashit {
  outline: solid;
}
.dashit:not(:focus):empty:before {
   content: '-';
}
```

```html
<span class="dashit" contenteditable="true">Remove this content and see how it "jumps up" when it's focused...</span>
```

Comment: Your demo is working as intended (based on the behavior you're asking for) in Chrome 67 for Windows. The dash only appears both when the span's content is deleted and the element loses focus. What browser/device is giving you trouble?

Comment: Firefox. Let me try some other ones. The issue is that the cursor shows up below where it's supposed to when empty and focused.

Comment: Working for me, too. (Ubuntu, FF 61)

Comment: @JonUleis Yes, works in Safari and Chrome but not in Firefox Dev 62.0b5 on Mac here.

Comment: It works if I add `display: inline-block` and a fixed height, but would love to avoid that. At least the fixed height. Ideas?

Comment: Does this only happen with an outline and not a border? I notice you changed it to an outline, which causes legacy (pre-Quantum) Firefox to display the same buggy behavior (don't ask me why I'm still using it...). It does not break when a border is used.

Comment: @BoltClock yes, the outline gave a different result. Any workarounds except for setting a height?